# Unable to update Body of iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, dhtml, script#

I have the below issue:

```
EmailBodyIFrame = (IFrameElement)DomElement.GetElementById("descriptionEditIFrame", this.editContainer.Children[0]);
EmailBodyIFrame.SetAttribute("url", url.ToString()); //works

EmailBodyIFrame.ContentWindow.Document.Body.Style.WordWrap = "break-word"; //does not work
```

And this is my HTML structure.

[image]

The issue is the changes made to body element are not reflecting in UI. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried sorting out your uppercase and lowercase letters? as it does not conform to the typical [style guide](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_conventions.asp).

try:

```
EmailBodyIFrame.contentWindow.document.body.style.wordWrap = "break-word";
```

Comment: The code given above is in Script#, so`.contentWindow.document.body.style.wordWrap = 'break-word';` is what I see in console.